# Secure way to allow users to log in with a single unique code (no username)?

Tags: php, security, passwords

I am creating a website whereby users are given an account by invitation only, and are sent a unique code by post. Users can then log in (at least the first time) by entering the code only.

The goal of this is for it to be extremely easy to understand and use by non tech-savvy people.

- User accounts will contain name, email, maybe address if the user wants to add it. No other sensitive information.
- The site itself would not be of interest to anyone other than those invited, and will not be indexed by search engines.

If you imagine the users are receiving a piece of mail in the post which says something along the lines of:

```
 Please visit www.example.com
 Log in with your unique code:

            A6XH3
```

As for the code, it must be extremely easy to remember and enter.

- I was planning four or five upper case alphanumeric characters - e.g. **A6XH3** - because I don't want anyone to have to enter a long hash or complicated string. I think 6 characters is the limit that I would deem acceptable for people to enter in this format.
- An alternative idea I had was to use two/three easy to spell words, such as `[adjective] [noun]` which would be more fun and seem less "techy" to the users - e.g. **pretty blue flower** - which would be more in keeping with the spirit of the site.

**Caveat**

Website administrators must be able to see all the users' codes in plain text, so they can mail them out in the first place and/or offer support to anyone unable to log in. They may also need to generate a new code for some reason, and tell the person directly.

Is there any alternative to storing the codes as plain text in the database?

**Questions**

1. Is this secure enough for the context? i.e. The only people who know about the site are those invited, and there is no real motive for anyone else to try to force their way in.
2. Would you use either of my methods of unique code generation, and if not what would you suggest as a better solution?
3. Is there another way I could allow a simple login without compromising security or simplicity of use without a username?

**Reminder**

There is NO registration process and users don't choose their own code. Their account is created by the website administrator, and the site randomly generates a unique code for them.

Comment: There's always a motive to break into anything, to have *that* feeling. Try not to think "there's no motive", because someone will maybe do the old "hey, I hacked your site. Will tell you where it's vulnerable for $50,000, else I publish everyones info."

Comment: I would probably add a time limit for that unique ID

Comment: If you must store codes in plain text for the purposes of user friendliness, do not allow users to set their own. The reason for this is the same reason stored passwords must be hashed: against all advice, users still reuse email/password combinations, and are accidentally handing over the credentials to their social media, email and other accounts. Don't let them do that on yours, especially if security is intended not to be paramount.

Comment: If you can avoid sending out codes via email, that is also good. Give them a link (as @Andre says, an expiring one) and that can generate a passcode for them.

Comment: If you hold their e-mail address, why not send them an e-mail with a one-time login code? Better yet, send them an SMS? Sending an SMS is more secure than using the e-mail approach. Also, perhaps having a simple code *and* the SMS (two-factor authentication) for them to login. (Users could have the ability to disable the TFA perhaps?)

Comment: Another way could be to use the unique ID and every x login with that key ask a security question, something like "whats your mums name" .. Obviously these question would have set in the registration process.

Comment: See: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/password_strength.png

Comment: @halfer Users don't set their own code. It's pre-generated once for them.

Comment: @Andre Potentially they may not log in for months. A time limit would then be somewhat pointless or restrictive.

Comment: @BadHorsie, you could perhaps use voice recognition? This would obviously still have its limits. I don't see how it would be possible to this with out security breaches.

Comment: @Andre Yeah I know it's a security nightmare, I was wondering if anyone had any bright ideas which makes it "secure enough" but still meets the goals of the user experience. I might have to just give up on it and rethink the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ultimately, no.** Authenticating with a single piece of information is dangerous. I touched on this subject when I covered [securely implementing "remember me" checkboxes](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2). Your database lookups are going to leak timing information and allow attackers to trivially guess a valid code. (And implementing [constant-time search algorithms](https://wingolog.org/archives/2014/12/02/there-are-no-good-constant-time-data-structures) is not a good idea.)

Having an authentication mechanism based solely on one value is a very bad idea. Always have two inputs: one for database lookups, the other for constant-time validation.

In most authentication systems, the username is used for the database lookup:

```
$userData = $pgsql->dbQuery("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ?", array(
    $_POST['username']
));
```

...and the password is, ideally, compared outside of the DB query:

```
if(\password_verify($_POST['password'], $userData[0]['passwordhash'])) { 
    /* good password */
}
```

Aside from timing leaks (which may lead to [timing attacks](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/its-all-about-time.html)), having only one factor means that you can't benefit from a per-user salt without evaluating every single user in your database (which would be an enormous performance drag with a sufficiently large number of users).

With these requirements, you have to do something like:

```
$result = $pgsql->dbQuery("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE password = ?", array(
    hash($algo, $_POST['password'])
));
```

...which goes completely against best practices.

My advice: Bite the bullet and either use two pieces of information (an identifier and an authenticator), or eschew authentication completely and work with OAuth, OpenID, SQRL, Mozilla Personas, etc. Feel free to implement this if you really want to, but it will not be secure.

Comment: "Always have two inputs: one for database lookups, the other for constant-time validation" - what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2):

**Is this secure enough for the context? i.e. The only people who know about the site are those invited, and there is no real motive for anyone else to try to force their way in.**

Not really, as it would allow an attacker (disregard the notion of 'no motive to force their way in') to brute force a login - just like any other login system, apart from in this instance you'd only have to try `four or five upper case alphanumeric characters` and not an e-mail and a password that adheres to various character sets.

Of course, you could do the following to help prevent a brute-force;

- Add a captcha to fill on every login request
- Two-factor authentication via SMS or E-Mail.

[image: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/password_strength.png]

**Would you use either of my methods of unique code generation, and if not what would you suggest as a better solution?**

Both methods are *fine* in my opinion, as it's just like a site not enforcing "strong" password character sets. *However*, the reason for the code to be in plain text is no different than storing passwords (in the conventional sense) in plain text - you just don't.

- Generate the random code
- Send it to the user (securely)
- Encrypt the code and store in the database

**Is there another way I could allow a simple login without compromising security or simplicity of use without a username?**

Simplicity is a relative term as it depends on your users. I would strongly recommended adding two-factor authentication via SMS or e-mail as outlined to my answer to your first question.

You could also use social media APIs to login. You'd then be giving the security to the social media platform and the user (without holding all the security concerns on your end, to some degree).

[image: social login]

---

To raise points in your question that weren't explicitly defined as a question.

**Website administrators must be able to see all the users' codes in plain text, so they can mail them out in the first place and/or offer support to anyone unable to log in**

No. I see no reason why you'd need any human interaction, nor have a site administrator to see the passcodes in plain text - anything your administrators can see, a hacker can see.

When a user is unable to login, they should verify their identity via e-mail or SMS or security questions (or all three?), and have a new code generated for them via the system and sent to the user. The new passcode should be immediately encrypted and saved into your database.

**User accounts will contain name, email, maybe address if the user wants to add it. No other sensitive information.**

Any data that can be used to identify someone (for example their name, email and address) is considered sensitive.

Comment: I am aware of the very popular XKCD comic, hence why I was considering the idea. The problem with encrypting the code and sending it "securely" is that it has to be posted by physical snail mail to these people. The administrator needs to know what the code is.

Comment: Is sending a passcode via physical mail your only option? What about a 2 step signup whereby a user inputs their email, address (anything where you can search your whitelist for invites) and you send their passcode to their mobile phone or email address

Comment: Yes, physical mail is one of the goals of this whole thing. Administrators of the site will want to send out physical mail. Users might also be elderly people, for example, who have access to the Internet via a friend or family member, but don't know how to use SMS properly (or don't own a phone) and don't have an email address.

Comment: The other problem is that the administrator enters the user details in the first place (i.e. registers them without them knowing) so the user when logging in doesn't necessarily know exactly what the data stored for them is. So if I asked them to enter their name, the administrator might have misspelled it or entered a different name (e.g. Your name is William but nobody calls you that. Did the administrator register you as William, Will or Bill?) I want to avoid any chance of confusion or frustration where these people are potentially technophobic and will give up if doesn't work first time.

Comment: Ah, I see. Perhaps you'd get a better response for that over at http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are many good ways of doing this, if you don't want to change the unique code. You could use API's for IP location and then you could create like a pattern of the places where the user has logged in from and then once you have enough data of the location, IP, maybe user agent? or even ISP you could use an algorithm to determine any alterations in pattern you collected, and then block that user account temporary till he/she confirms it was them using the account?

This is just an idea, its kind of complex and probably to extreme for some people, but that's what I would try to do if I just waned a login system based on a unique key.

Comment: There can be no blocking of accounts, verification required, etc. Imagine it's your Grandma trying to log in. Alternatively, it will likely be used by people from their phone in cases where they are tech-savvy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way, as you would do a with a password-reset page:

1. Let the user register with his email.
2. Send a link with a token to the user, a *hash* of the token is stored in the database.
3. If the user clicks the link and if the token is valid, welcome him and let him enter his own password.

If you send the user a link with a token, (s)he can simply click this link and does not have to enter a code anywhere. The token can then be a strong token like:

http://www.example.com/register/8eM2WwsuR59MnmyswYoQ

In the database you should store only a hash of this token, though if the token is strong, the hash can be unsalted and the algorithm can be fast like SHA256. When you implement it this way, you also have the password-reset for free.